# tomcat jvm arguments lost

Tags: bash, tomcat

I want to run tomcat with a javaagent.

setenv.sh:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/ggfan/1-install/java/jdk1.8.0_271
export CATALINA_OPTS="${CATALINA_OPTS} -javaagent:/home/ggfan/2-work/centuari-space/jdbc-leak-detector/target/jdbcld.jar=/home/ggfan/3-tmp/logs/jdbcld,INFO,org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource\$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper"
```

call startup.sh, seems tomcat picked it correctly:

```
[ggfan@localhost bin]$ ./startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/ggfan/1-install/apache-tomcat-8.5.64
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/ggfan/1-install/apache-tomcat-8.5.64
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/ggfan/1-install/apache-tomcat-8.5.64/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /home/ggfan/1-install/java/jdk1.8.0_271
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/ggfan/1-install/apache-tomcat-8.5.64/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/ggfan/1-install/apache-tomcat-8.5.64/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_OPTS:    -javaagent:/home/ggfan/2-work/centuari-space/jdbc-leak-detector/target/jdbcld.jar=/home/ggfan/3-tmp/logs/jdbcld,INFO,org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
Tomcat started.
```

however, from tomcat log:

```
24-Sep-2021 15:45:04.437 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：       -javaagent:/home/ggfan/2-work/centuari-space/jdbc-leak-detector/target/jdbcld.jar=/home/ggfan/3-tmp/logs/jdbcld,INFO,org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource
```

inner class name after '$' sign get lost and the real argument received by my javaagent is the incomplete one.

what is wrong?

I am running with tomcat Apache Tomcat/8.5.64 on fedora 31

Comment: From what you posted, it seems that by the time `setenv.sh` is evaluated, the variable `PoolGuardConnectionWrapper` is undefined.

Comment: To guard yourself against this type of errors, put a `set -u` at the start of each of your bash scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to split `CATALINA_OPTS` into words an pass them as arguments to `java`, the `catalina.sh` script uses [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-eval):

```sh
eval exec "\"$_RUNJAVA\"" "\"$CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG\"" $LOGGING_MANAGER "$JAVA_OPTS" "$CATALINA_OPTS" \
...
```

this obviously performs variable expansion on `$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper`. To prevent this escape the dollar sign twice:

```sh
export CATALINA_OPTS="${CATALINA_OPTS} ...PoolingDataSource\\\$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper"
```